# Ruby on Rails: passing value from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I have calculated some value in a javascript based upon user inputs and now I want to set a variable present in controller function to the calculate value. Is it possible to do so or is there a better approach?

Comment: You can do it if you pass the javascript variable as a parameter to your controller and set the variable

Comment: You can use "view helpers" for this approach..

Answer (score 2):

Are you sending a param with the javascript? Then just set:

`@variable = params[:calculate]`

Answer (score 0):

Set the value into a `hidden_field_tag` in side the form,then you can get the value in `params`.

Ex.

In js script

```
document.getElementsByName('js_hidden').value = 1111;
```

then the value will assign into the hidden_field_tag

like

```
hidden_field_tag 'from_js',1111,:id=>"js_hidden"
```

then

in your controller you can get `params[:from_js]`.

More details [click here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)